# Invoking a WCF WebInvoke method with HttpWebRequest POST and mapping parameters correctly

Tags: wcf

I have successfully setup the following WCF contract as a service:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "submit/{apiKey}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
[OperationContract]
DataServiceResult Submit(string apiKey, string email);
```

I am trying to call this using a HttpWebRequest

```
string url = "http://localhost:51462/Api.svc/web/submit/key";
string formatString = "email=hello@there.com";

byte[] postData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formatString);

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "POST";
request.Referer = url;
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = postData.Length;

System.IO.Stream outputStream = request.GetRequestStream();
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
outputStream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
outputStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
string srcString = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

When I run this code the apikey is successfully mapped. The issue is that I am not sure how to map the email parameter to the submit method which currently is null.

Another note, in my application I am passing 10-15 parameters as string so adding email to the UriTemplate is not the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just checking, why isn't passing an object (XML or JSON) in the URL an option?

Can you have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943554/how-to-send-custom-object-to-wcf-rest-service-in-browser-based-url) for reference. Let me know if i got it all wrong :)